# Add array items to array in one line

Tags: ruby, csv

I am building a CSV object and I have a dynamic set of header items. I build this 'header' row as follows:

```
headers = ["name", "email"]
questions.each do |q|
  headers << q
end
csv << headers
```

Although this works just fine, what I would like to do is have the call in one line without having to add the `headers` variable first.

So something like:

```
csv << ["name", "email", questions.each { |q| q }]
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because the `each` returns the 'questions' array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
csv << headers + questions
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the splat operator as follow.

```
csv << ["name", "email", *questions]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Array#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
csv << ["name", "email"] + questions
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
csv << %w(name email) + questions
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several methods to do this. I would use something like this:

```
headers = (['name', 'email'] << questions).flatten
```

See this question for more elaborate answers, also in regard to performance: [How do you add an array to another array in Ruby and not end up with a multi-dimensional result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801516/how-do-you-add-an-array-to-another-array-in-ruby-and-not-end-up-with-a-multi-dim)

Answer (score 0):

```
["name", "email", *questions.map { |q| q }]
```

`map` returns result array

Comment: `objects.map { |q| q }` isn't the same as `objects` ?

Comment: Only in this case, but if u want to do smth with each element and return a result object u need to use `map`