# How to rewrite this each loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, each

I have this loop:

```
  stations = Station.where(...)
  stations.all.each do |s|
    if s.city_id == city.id
      show_stations << s
    end
  end
```

This works well, but because of looping the all the data, I think it's kinda slow. I've tried to rewrite it with using `select`, like this:

```
show_stations << stations.select { |station| station.city_id == city.id}
```

But the amount of saved data into `show_stations` is different compared to the `each` version and then, the data are in different format (array/object).

Is there any better/faster way to rewrite the loop version?

Comment: where does `city` come from? The more logic you can put into the `where` clause, the faster the code will be because the returned dataset will be smaller.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest version of this maybe the built-in rails ActiveRecord method for finding associated objects.

So provided your Station model contains this:

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
```

And your City model contains this:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stations
```

Then rails automatically generates the method `city.stations` which automatically fetches the stations which contain that city's id from the database. It should be pretty optimized. 

If you want to make it even faster then you can add `add_index :stations, :city_id` to your table in a migration and it will retrieve faster. Note that this only saves time when you have a lot of stations to search through.

If you need to make it an array you can just convert it after with `city.stations.to_a`. And if you wanted to narrow it further, just use the `select` method and add the conditions that you wanted to previously add in your `Station.where(...)` statement. 
(e.g. `city.stations.to_a.select { |item| your_filter }`)

Answer (score 1):

You should also cache the query results like

```
    stations ||= Station.where("your where").where(:city_id => city.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Station appears to be an active record model. If that is the case, and you don't need all the stations, you can add the `city.id` filter to your `where` statement.

The issue you're having now is that you're adding the array returned from `select` as the last item of `show_stations`. If you want `show_stations` to only contain stations that match `city.id` then use `show_stations = ...` rather than `show_stations << ...`. If you want `show_stations` to contain what it already contains plus the stations that match `city.id` then use `show_stations + stations.select { |station| station.city_id == city.id }`. (There are [a number of other approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801516/how-do-you-add-an-array-to-another-array-in-ruby-and-not-end-up-with-a-multi-dim) for adding two arrays together.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to include into the `where` clause the city parameter:

```
stations = Station.where("your where").where(:city_id => city.id)
```

or the same

```
stations = Station.where("your where").where('city_id = ?', city.id)
```