# How does `Array#<<` work?

Tags: arrays, ruby, immutability

Suppose I declare arrays as follows:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = array1
```

The object ID of both arrays are the same:

```
array1.object_id = 118945940
array2.object_id = 118945940
```

When I insert an element in an array as follows,

```
array1 << 10
```

the result is

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
```

But when I add new array into array `array1`,

```
array1 = array1 + [11,12]

array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12]
array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
```

the object ID of both arrays have changed.

How does `<<` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the confusion here is due to the fact that concatenating two arrays actually creates a new array (ie: a new object).

```
array1 + array2
```

This will create a new array with the contents of both arrays inside. So the object id will change because it is a different object.

When you use the `<<` operator it just adds an element to the array - ruby doesn't create a new object and hence both arrays (which share an object id) get the new element.

Comment: So is `<<` like `array.append`?

Comment: @Arc676 - Yes. This is my intention.

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801516/how-do-you-add-an-array-to-another-array-in-ruby-and-not-end-up-with-a-multi-dim, while not directly related to your question contains useful and relevant information to your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no **need** to create a new object"? `<<` just **doesn't** create a new object.

Comment: @sawa - perhaps the wrong choice of words... What I mean is that appending an element to an array does not create a new object. You don't need to use code/methods that creates a new object.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is a variable containing a reference (pointer, handle, ID - whatever you want to call it) to the actual array (the instance of class `Array`).

```
array (variable)   -------------------> object (instance of class Array)
```

What does your code do? Let's see:

```
array << value
```

This is exactly the same as calling a method: `array.append(value)`. No new instance of `Array` is created. You are not assigning a new value to the variable `array`. The actual array object is of course changing, but not its reference.

```
array1 = array1 + array2
```

The right side of the assignment, `array1 + array2`, must necessarily create a new `Array` instance. This is easy to see - the code intuitively should not modify `array1` or `array2`. The reference to this new array is then stored in the variable `array1`.