# Rspec how to create an method to "DRY" only some params of a request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to test a create method of my project, but this create method has 3 steps in my form and I want to test all of them. To test each step I need to send a create request with their respective params of the step.

The problem is: I am repeating many params in each step, I want to know how can I put the common params in a method and then just call it.

Here is my rspec file

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::MenteeApplicationsController, type: :controller do
    describe "Api Mentee Application controller tests" do
        let(:edition) { create(:edition) }

        it 'should start create a Mentee Application, step 1' do
            edition
            post :create, application: {
                first_name: "Mentee", last_name: "Rspec", email: "mentee@email.com",
                gender: "female", country: "IN", program_country: "IN",
                time_zone: "5 - Mumbai", communicating_in_english: "true",
                send_to_mentor_confirmed: "true",
                time_availability: 3,
                previous_programming_experience: "false" },
                step: "1", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end

        it 'should continue to create a Mentee Application, step 2' do
            post :create, application: {
                first_name: "Mentee", last_name: "Rspec", email: "mentee@email.com",
                gender: "female", country: "IN", program_country: "IN",
                time_zone: "5 - Mumbai", communicating_in_english: "true",
                send_to_mentor_confirmed: "true",
                time_availability: 3,
                motivation: "Motivation",
                background: "Background",
                team_work_experience: "Team Work Experience",
                previous_programming_experience: "false" },
                step: "2", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end

        it 'should not create a Mentee Application in api format' do
            applications = MenteeApplication.count
            post :create, application: {
                first_name: "Mentee", last_name: "Rspec", email: "mentee@email.com",
                gender: "female", country: "IN", program_country: "IN",
                time_zone: "5 - Mumbai", communicating_in_english: "true",
                send_to_mentor_confirmed: "true",
                motivation: "Motivation",
                background: "Background",
                team_work_experience: "Team Work Experience",
                previous_programming_experience: "false", experience: "",
                operating_system: "mac_os",
                project_proposal: "Project Proposal",
                roadmap: "Roadmap",
                time_availability: 3,
                engagements: ["master_student", "part_time", "volunteer", "one_project"] },
            step: "3", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
            expect(MenteeApplication.count).to be(0)
        end

        it 'should create a Mentee Application in api format (step 3)' do
            applications = MenteeApplication.count
            post :create, application: {
                first_name: "Mentee", last_name: "Rspec", email: "mentee@email.com",
                gender: "female", country: "IN", program_country: "IN",
                time_zone: "5 - Mumbai", communicating_in_english: "true",
                send_to_mentor_confirmed: "true",
                motivation: "Motivation",
                background: "Background",
                programming_language: "ruby",
                team_work_experience: "Team Work Experience",
                previous_programming_experience: "false", experience: "",
                operating_system: "mac_os",
                project_proposal: "Project Proposal",
                roadmap: "Roadmap",
                time_availability: 3,
                engagements: ["master_student", "part_time", "volunteer", "one_project"] },
            step: "3", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
            expect(MenteeApplication.count).to be(applications+1)
            expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Thank you for your application!")
        end

    end
end
```

As you can see, the params in step 1 are used in steps 2 and 3, so I was thinking in something like this:

```
def some_params
    params.require(:application).permit(first_name: "Mentee", last_name: "Rspec", email: "mentee@email.com",
            gender: "female", country: "IN", program_country: "IN",
            time_zone: "5 - Mumbai", communicating_in_english: "true",
            send_to_mentor_confirmed: "true",
            time_availability: 3,
            previous_programming_experience: "false")
end
```

But didn't work, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` blocks allow you to define variables for using within the tests cases (`it`s). Some key points to be aware of:

- They are lazily evaluated: code within the block is not run until you call the variable (unless you use a bang -- `let!` -- which forces the evaluation)
- They might be overridden within inner `context`s

Head to [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) to know more about them.

---

The code you provided could make use of `let`s just like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::MenteeApplicationsController, type: :controller do
    describe "Api Mentee Application controller tests" do
        let(:edition) { create(:edition) }
        let(:first_step_params) do
          {
            first_name: 'Mentee',
            last_name: 'Rspec',
            #...
            previous_programming_experience: false,
          }
        end
        let(:second_step_params) do
          {
            motivation: "Motivation",
            background: "Background",
            team_work_experience: "Team Work Experience",
          }.merge(first_step_params)
        end
        let(:third_step_params) do
          {
            operating_system: "mac_os",
            project_proposal: "Project Proposal",
            roadmap: "Roadmap",
            time_availability: 3,
            engagements: ["master_student", "part_time", "volunteer", "one_project"],
          }.merge(third_step_params)
        end

        it 'should start create a Mentee Application, step 1' do
            edition                                                          

            post :create, application: first_step_params, step: "1", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)                        
        end                                                                  

        it 'should continue to create a Mentee Application, step 2' do       
            post :create, application: second_step_params, step: "2", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)                        
        end

        it 'should not create a Mentee Application in api format' do
            applications = MenteeApplication.count

            post :create, application: third_step_params, step: "3", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
            expect(MenteeApplication.count).to be(0)
        end
    end
end
```

### Additional suggestions

#### 1. Do not implement controller specs

Controllers are meant to be a thin software layer between the user interface and background services. Their tests can hardly be acknowledged as integration (end-to-end) nor unit tests.

I'd suggest you to implement feature specs instead. ([capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/#using-capybara-with-rspec) is a great match for Rails testing with RSpec)

This [blog post](https://medium.com/table-xi/whats-up-with-rails-controller-tests-f0ece1fdd9f0) might provide more insights on this.

#### 2. Do not use should in your test cases descriptions

See [betterspecs.org](http://www.betterspecs.org/#should).

#### 3. Mind the last trailing comma in

```
let(:application_params) do                                                      
  {                                                                  
    first_name: 'Mentee',                                            
    last_name: 'Rspec',                                              
    #...                          
    previous_programming_experience: false,
  }                                                                  
end
```

It prevents [incidental changes](https://www.rubytapas.com/2012/11/16/episode-024-incidental-change/).

#### 4. Use a .rspec file

With contents such as

```
--require rails_helper
```

So you don't need `require 'rails_helper'` on top of each spec file.

#### 5. Use `context`s

This is also a guidance from betterspecs.org. You could do something like

```
RSpec.describe Api::MenteeApplicationsController, type: :controller do
    describe "Api Mentee Application controller tests" do
        let(:edition) { create(:edition) }
        let(:application_params) do
          {
            #...
          }
        end
        let(:step) { 1 }

        it 'should start create a Mentee Application' do
            edition

            post :create, application: application_params, step: step, steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end

        context 'in second step' do
          let(:step) { 2 }

          it 'should continue to create a Mentee Application' do
              post :create, application: application_params, step: step, steps: "3"

              expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
          end
        end
    end
end
```

`context`s might also be handy for handling additional params:

```
RSpec.describe Api::MenteeApplicationsController, type: :controller do
  describe "Api Mentee Application controller tests" do
    let(:edition) { create(:edition) }
    let(:application_params) do
      common_params.merge(additional_params)
    end
    let(:commom_params) do
      {
        #...
      }
    end
    let(:additional_params) { {} }

    it 'creates an application' do
      post :create, application: application_params
    end

    context 'with API params' do
      let(:additional_params) do
        {
          #...
        }
      end

      it 'creates an application' do
        post :create, application: application_params
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the `post` method call became exactly the same in both contexts. This would allow for reusing it (in a `before` block or even another `let` block).

Comment: This however doesn't provide the new application params.

Comment: Thanks @JohanWentholt. I've updated the answer. What do you think?

Comment: I don't want to be the annoying one, but you've added the step 3 params, but still left out step 2.

Comment: @MatheusSantana this works for step 1 but I can't make it work for step 2 and 3. Code of step 2: `post :create, application: application_params {
    motivation: "Motivation",
    background: "Background",
    team_work_experience: "Team Work Experience" },
    step: "2", steps: "3"`

Comment: @LucasAndrade @JohanWentholt I'm sorry, I hadn't noticed the differing params for these steps. I've updated the answer (but the main idea remains the same: using `let`s). Does it work now?

Comment: @MatheusSantana I deleted my answer since it doesn't add anything anymore. Your answer seems pretty solid now. (Y)

Comment: One last thing to keep in mind by having the merge with the previous params at the end, is that it overwrites the hash you're creating. This means if you have two conflicting keys the value of the previous params is chosen. If you don't want this behavior you have to change the order and call _#merge_ on the previous params, supplying the new additions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would be tempted to do it something like below. Essentially:

1. Create a memoized variable called `@full_application` and wrap it in a method (I've done this at the bottom of the test).
2. Create constants stipulating the subsets of the values that you want for each test, such as `STEP_ONE_PARAMS`, `STEP_TWO_PARAMS`, etc.
3. In each `it` block, use `.slice` and the constants defined above to "grab" the values from `full_application` that you want to use.

Something  like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::MenteeApplicationsController, type: :controller do

  STEP_ONE_PARAMS = %w(
    first_name
    last_name
    email
    gender
    country
    communicating_in_english
    send_to_mentor_confirmed
    time_availability
    previous_programming_experience
  ).freeze

  STEP_TWO_PARAMS = STEP_ONE_PARAMS.dup.concat(%w(
    motivation
    background
    team_work_experience
  )).freeze

  STEP_THREE_PARAMS = STEP_TWO_PARAMS.dup.concat(%w(
    operating_system
    project_proposal
    roadmap
    engagements
  )).freeze

    describe "Api Mentee Application controller tests" do
        let(:edition) { create(:edition) }

        it 'should start create a Mentee Application, step 1' do
            edition
            post :create, application: full_application.slice(*STEP_ONE_PARAMS),
                step: "1", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end

        it 'should continue to create a Mentee Application, step 2' do
            post :create, application: full_application.slice(*STEP_TWO_PARAMS),
                step: "2", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
        end

        it 'should not create a Mentee Application in api format' do
            applications = MenteeApplication.count
            post :create, application: full_application.slice(*STEP_THREE_PARAMS),
            step: "3", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
            expect(MenteeApplication.count).to be(0)
        end

        it 'should create a Mentee Application in api format (step 3)' do
            applications = MenteeApplication.count
            post :create, application: full_application,
            step: "3", steps: "3"

            expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
            expect(MenteeApplication.count).to be(applications+1)
            expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("Thank you for your application!")
        end

    end
end


def full_application
  @full_application ||= {
    first_name:                       "Mentee", 
    last_name:                        "Rspec", 
    email:                            "mentee@email.com",
    gender:                           "female", 
    country:                          "IN", 
    program_country:                  "IN",
    time_zone:                        "5 - Mumbai", 
    communicating_in_english:         "true",
    send_to_mentor_confirmed:         "true",
    motivation:                       "Motivation",
    background:                       "Background",
    programming_language:             "ruby",
    team_work_experience:             "Team Work Experience",
    previous_programming_experience:  "false", 
    experience:                       "",
    operating_system:                 "mac_os",
    project_proposal:                 "Project Proposal",
    roadmap:                          "Roadmap",
    time_availability:                3,
    engagements: [
      "master_student", 
      "part_time", 
      "volunteer", 
      "one_project"
    ] 
  }
end
```

Comment: Why use `arr1.dup.concat(arr2)` over `arr1 + arr2`? Or did you not know about the `+` method on arrays?

Comment: Oh, wow! There's a `+` method on arrays?!? BTW, `concat` and `+` are not the same. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801516/how-do-you-add-an-array-to-another-array-in-ruby-and-not-end-up-with-a-multi-dim) one Q&A on the topic, although there are a lot of them out there. In this particular instance, the OP could probably go either way without great consequence.